# OpenGL ES Load saved image back into renderbuffer

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I did some testing on GLPaint and managed to save the image. But now, my problem for is I have no idea how to load the saved image back to render buffer so I can continue editing. Would be glad if someone can show the code and the idea behind, I am very new to OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0):

If you say, that you saved the image, then to load it back and display you have to create a texture object and map it to some polygons. Check [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html).